# Express Nodejs app crash without error message with nodemon and babel

Tags: node.js, error-handling, console, babeljs, nodemon

I have an express nodejs app running with nodemon, however when app crashed, there is no error message logged in console:
[image]

Here is my index.js file:

```
/* eslint-disable */
require("babel-register");
require('./server.js');
```

I don't think this is a `nodemon` problem because when I remove `babel`, console would show error message that 'import' is not defined:
[image]

Currently for babel I use

```
{
  "presets": ["env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-runtime", {
          "helpers": false,
          "polyfill": false,
          "regenerator": true,
          "moduleName": "babel-runtime"
        }]
  ]
}
```

because of the `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`
I tried switching node version, didn't work. Current node version v8.10.0

Would really appreciate if somebody can help me out. It is really a pain to debug without the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for those who encounter the same problem, I ended up solving the problem by this:

```
/* eslint-disable */
require("babel-register");
try{
    require('./server.js');
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

If this still doesn't work, then listen to `unhandledRejection` and `uncaughtException` as well by:

```
process
    .on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
        console.error(reason, 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise', p);
    })
    .on('uncaughtException', err => {
        console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');
        process.exit(1);
    });
```